# How to use write.xlsx to write the column to the specific column

Tags: r

```
    get_Close <- function(i,p,f){
        #read the symbol from the excel 
        library("readxl");
        symbols <- read_excel('test1.xlsx',col_names = FALSE);
        inputI <-i;
        inputP <-p;
        inputF <-f;
        #do a for loop here 
        amount <-nrow(symbols);
        for (i in 1:amount){
        inputQ <-symbols[i,];
        print(inputQ);
        dataSave<-getClose(inputQ,inputI,inputP,inputF);
        library(xlsx);
        write.xlsx(dataSave, "output.xlsx",sheetName ="Close Price",row.names = FALSE,col.names = FALSE); 
         }

    }
```

getClose is a function that could get a column of data from a url. Is there anyway to use the write.xlsx to put every column into different column in excel? Like the first dataSave to Column A in excel, and the second to B...

Comment: `write.xlsx`will write columns of your data frame as colomns in excel. so not really sure what you are asking? if you want help make a reproducible example and show your desired output

Comment: In the for loop, everytime I will get a column, and I use the write.xlsx to write into a excvel file. But all the column I got in the for loop will write into the same position in the excel file. So finally, I could only get the last column I got in the for loop.

Comment: would writing all of your columns to a dataframe in R inside of your function, then calling write.xlsx after be acceptable? or do you want to update excel on the fly for each column

Comment: I tried to write all columns to a dataframe, but I could not figure the correct way.

Comment: are the columns always the same length?

Comment: Yes, should be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without having all of your initial information this is where I would start. I'm assuming `getClose()` is returning a vector.

```
get_Close <- function(i,p,f){
    #read the symbol from the excel 
    library("readxl");
    symbols <- read_excel('test1.xlsx',col_names = FALSE);
    inputI <-i;
    inputP <-p;
    inputF <-f;
    #do a for loop here 
    amount <-nrow(symbols);
    #initialize an empty list to build out all your columns
    col_list <- list()
    for (i in 1:amount){
      inputQ <-symbols[i,];
      print(inputQ);
      dataSave<-getClose(inputQ,inputI,inputP,inputF);
      col_list <- c(col_list, list(dataSave))
     }
#use do.call to turn your list into a matrix
output <- do.call(cbind, col_list)
#coherce that matrix to a dataframe
output <- as.data.frame(output)
return(output)
}
library(xlsx);
#should be ready to write output to your xlsx destination
write.xlsx(output, "output.xlsx",sheetName ="Close Price",row.names = FALSE,col.names = FALSE);
```

Comment: Really appreciate it.